# Forgot the pattern for my one plus 7t pro mobile, how to recovery it?

Tags: mobile, data-recovery, password-recovery, oneplus7

i have forget the pattern for my 1+ 7T pro mobile. It is not linked with gmail account. i need the data nearly 200 GB. How to recover that data from it ? is there any other way to unlock the mobile ?, there is no forget pattern option is shown or i have tried with google find my device also. it is not shown. i can able to connect my mobile to my wifi network.  I need to recover the 200 GB of data. Is there any way (including hacking) ?  , if any please suggest.

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow is for programming questions only.